# How to get image to take up whole screen on press using Transform with React Native

Tags: react-native, transform, css-transforms

I'm creating a chat app and want to make a picture take up the whole screen when it is clicked on like in other chat apps. The code I have so far scales it to the whole screen and centers it horizontally, but only because I know where on the X axis it is starting at and then calculate the translateX from there. The problem is that, for the Y axis, an image can be anywhere on the screen when it is clicked so I can't do the same thing I did for translateX. How can I get the Y position of the image to calculate how much I need to translate it on the Y Axis.

I know there were similar solutions that use spring, but I like the look of the image expanding from where it begins rather than it coming up from the bottom.

Here is my current code:

```
<Animated.View
        style={[
          styles.fadingContainer,
          {
            transform: [
              {
                scale: Anim.interpolate({
                  inputRange: [0, 0.5, 1],
                  outputRange: [1, 1.5, 2],
                }),
              },
              {
                translateX: Anim.interpolate({
                  inputRange: [0, 0.5, 1],
                  outputRange: [
                    0,
                    Dimensions.get("window").width / 16,
                    Dimensions.get("window").width / 8,
                  ],
                }),
              },
              {
                translateY: Anim.interpolate({
                  inputRange: [0, 0.5, 1],
                  outputRange: [
                    ** What do I put here? ** 
                  ],
                }),
              },
            ],
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Text style={styles.fadingText}>Fading View!</Text>
      </Animated.View>
```

Comment: Why can you get the X position but can't get the Y?

Comment: I thought the message would always be on the same side since it's a message and all messages are aligned on the same side so I would know before hand, but I guess I wouldn't know X either because I wouldn't know if I was the one who sent it or if it was someone else (which dictates which side the message goes on)